# about the const in an operator overloading definition

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, constants

For the following definition of

```
const vector3F operator*(const vector3F &v, float s);
```

There are two `const`, what are their respective usages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The const-reference in the argument means that you don't change `v`, so you can pass constant vectors (and temporaries!) to the function. That's a Good Thing.

The constant by-value return is sort of a gimmick. It prevents you from writing things like this:

```
 vector3F v = get_vector();
 vector3F w = v;

 (v * 1.5) = w; // outch! Cannot assign to constant, though, so we're good.
```

Returning by-value as constant is problematic, though, since it interferes with C++11's rvalue references and move semantics:

```
 move_me(v * 1.5);  // cannot bind to `vector3F &&` :-(
```

Because of that, and because an abuse like the one I showed above is fairly unlikely to happen by accident, it's probably best to return by value only as non-constant.

Comment: Wouldn't returning const value also prevent this usage `somevar = (v * 1.5) * w;` ?

Comment: @RedX: Not if you're allowed to copy from a constant.

Answer (score 0):

The first const indicates that the return value is constant and can not be altered (which, by the way, is a bad idea for the multiplication operator):

```
const Vector3F v = myvector*100.0;

v.x = 0; // error: the vector is constant and can not be altered
```

The second const indicates that the argument "v" is constant:

```
const vector3F operator*(const vector3F &v, float s)
{
    v.x = 0; // error: "v" is constant
}
```

Comment: The error in your first example comes from the `const` in the declaration of `v`. Leave that out, without changing the `operator*`, and the whole thing will compile just fine.

Comment: Yes, it is a bad idea (see Kerrek SB's answer) but not for this reason.